# Excel VBA IF statement when label is clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create an if statement that completes an action depending on whether a data label within a chart has been selected/clicked. I tried below, but does not work.

```
If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate And _
   ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Datalabel.Select = True Then
  'do something
Else
  exit sub
End If
```

Comment: Good overview here: http://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/

Comment: The `.Activate` is a method and will not return the true/false you are looking for. What you want to do is insert a `_Click ` event for the chart using the drop down boxes that display the objects in the sheet you are working on.

Comment: Can someone provide some sample code that involves a _click event for a chart label? I would like a hand getting started.

Comment: AFAIK there is Click Event for a chart label. However, you could handle an event when the chart is changing in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple. In visual studio when youre in sub, if you change this drop down shown in the pic, it will automatically add the new sub for the new event handler.

[image]

```
Private Sub Stuff_Click()

If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate And _
   ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Select = True Then
  'do something
Else
  Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Then after you do that, just enter code like you normally would. THis is especially helpful with complicated userforms where lables,textboxes, comboboxes all need some kind of shit fired off on random events. A lot of the time you use it for data validation, but some people like putting that stuff in the main code as well.